# Set http header using httpurlconnection

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

Hi I have a problem setting the header of a http request, this is the code I'm using

```
    public static JSONObject getJSONObjectFromURL(String urlString, String version, String menuTop, String menuBottom) throws IOException, JSONException {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);

    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Mobile-Version", MessageFormat.format("android/{0}", version));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-Menu-Hash", menuTop);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("X-MenuBottom-Hash", menuBottom);

    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */ );
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */ );
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();

    //Log.d("-------------------....",urlConnection.getRequestProperty("X-Mobile-Version"));

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    br.close();

    String jsonString = sb.toString();
    Log.d("..........JSon", jsonString);

    return new JSONObject(jsonString);
}
```

but I always get the following error

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: endpoint/
W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:251)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
              at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source:0)
              at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1058)
              at com.example.bordi.hotel.DataManager.getJSONObjectFromURL(DataManager.java:109)
              at com.example.bordi.hotel.DataManager$1.run(DataManager.java:132)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

How can I solve? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are getting a `FileNotFoundException`, then it means the URL you are trying to download from is giving a 404 error (or one of the other 40x errors). Print out the value of `urlString`, and post it here.

Comment: I'm sure the url works fine because on the IOS version of the same app I can download the son from it, I think the error is in the header of the call because I'm not sure that's the correct way to set them

Comment: You are having what problem setting what header? NB The URL certainly does not work: @LeoAso is quite correct. Clearly the URL isn't what you think it is. And why are you calling `setDoOutput(true)` on a GET request? And then not doing any output? You're turning it into a POST request with no parameters.

Comment: @EJP in order to make the url work I have to set three header: X-Mobile-Version, X-Menu-Hash and X-MenuBottom-Hash, I set them using the code I have already paste but evidently I set them in the wrong way because the url doesn't work, my question is: is that the right way to set httheader?

Comment: You are jumping to conclusions. Setting headers wrongly doesn't cause 404 errors. For the third time, the problem here is the URL (`endpoint/`: doesn't look right to me), and all the other things I mentioned.

Comment: @EJP I'm getting the 403 error, if I simulate the call with postman (using the same url and setting the three headers) it works. I cant't explain why

Comment: Did you try it without the incorrect `setDoOutput(true)` call? As I suggested two days ago?

Comment: @EJP yes but nothing happened

Comment: 'Nothung happened' is already an improvement over an exception. Don't you think?

Comment: @EJP I have fixed changing this line:  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
```